# Is $M(n,\mathbb{R})$ a metric space?

Tags: general-topology, vector-spaces, metric-spaces

My question arises from the following reasoning:

We know that $M(n,\mathbb{R})$ (set of real matrix with size $n\times n$) is a real vector space of dimension $n^2$, then we can consider the canonical isomorphism given by
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\Phi:M(n,\mathbb{R})&\rightarrow& \mathbb{R}^{n^2} \\
\left[\begin{array}{cccc} |&|&&| \\ v_{1}&v_{2}&\cdots &v_{n} \\ |&|&&| \end{array} \right] &\mapsto & \left[\begin{array}{c} v_{1}\\v_{2} \\ \vdots \\ v_{n}\end{array} \right].
\end{array}
$$
Let $d$ the euclidean metric in $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$, then we define the function
$$\widetilde{d}:M(n,\mathbb{R})\times M(n,\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow [0,\infty)$$
such that for each $A,B\in M(n,\mathbb{R})$ is defined by
$$\widetilde{d}(A,B)=d(\Phi(A),\Phi(B)).$$

I have shown that $\widetilde{d}$ satisfies all the conditions to be metric.

**My question:** I find it suspicious because I have not found information about this form to induce a metric in a finite-dimensional vector space. if it is true, then all  finite-dimensional vector space is metric space.  Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: One always can endow a finite-dimensional vector space with the metric coming from this "base change", i.e. viewing it as an $\mathbf{R}^N$. And you can do the same with the norms: every finite-dimensional vector space is a normed space.

Comment: Your approach works in a general setting: let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, and let $\Phi:Y\rightarrow X$ be an injective map. Then $\overline{d}(y_1,y_2):=d(\Phi(y_1),\Phi(y_2))$ is a metric on $Y$.

Comment: The problem is that while all of these spaces are metric spaces, it may not be a metric space in the way that you 'want' - for instance, this metric isn't preserved under $n$-dimensional linear transformations, so it doesn't behave nicely with the linear structure that you're presumably using $n\times n$ matrices to investigate in the first place.